# Line search bracketing for proximal gradient. Is it good idea?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, convergence

Maybe my question is obvious but i cannot find any good source which answers it

I trying to learn about proximal gradient. One thing which is not clear for me is particular algorithm for line search.
According to [this presentation](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/c924/20f001e023c693db762758f9590571256e35.pdf) (slide 20) and some other sources backtracking line search with previous step length as initialization is good choice.

I implemented simple version of LASSO with proximal gradient and it looks like that increasing step from time to time can make convergence significantly faster.

So my question is: Is it good idea to use bracketing in proximal gradient?

(Accoring to "Numerical optimization by Nocedal and Wright" i use term "bracketing" in meaning "finding initial interval for backtracking")

My second question is: Which is best line search algorithm for LASSO/general proximal gradient?

Sorry for my English

Answer (score 1):

For LASSO Case you probably can estimate $ L $ pretty good and the best would be using FISTA for acceleration of the Proximal Gradient Method.

In general you can use the Line Search as above ([Neal Parikh and Stephen Boyd - Proximal Algorithms](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/c924/20f001e023c693db762758f9590571256e35.pdf) Page 20):

[image]

Or ([L. Vandenberghe - Proximal Gradient Method](http://www.seas.ucla.edu/~vandenbe/236C/lectures/proxgrad.pdf) Page 6-20):

[image]

I expect them to be equivalent, Though it seems Boyd's is easier computationally.

Better and more robust choice would be [Alternating Direction Method of Multipliers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Augmented_Lagrangian_method#Alternating_direction_method_of_multipliers) (ADMM).